# Batch file on Mac that makes a change to a bunch of files

Tags: macos, unix, csv, batch-processing

I'm new to making batch files and appreciate your help with what is probably a pretty simple question

I've got a bunch of files in a bunch of directories, like this:

```
dir-1/index.html
dir-2/index.html
dir-3/index.html
...
dir-150/index.html
```

Each file includes within the HTML the text "Replace with second column" and "Replace with third column"

Then, I have a tsv file with three columns of information, like this:

```
dir-1        dog          cat     
dir-2        mouse        frog
dir-3        circus       clown
...
dir-150      last         one
```

I am trying to batch edit each of the index.html files, to replace the text "Replace with second column" with the data in column 2, and "Replace with third column" with the data in column 3, for the specific directory listed in column 1.  Any ideas on how to do this in UNIX/Mac OSX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming **changes.tab** is has tab separated values like your example above (and not comma separated as you state), this should get you started:

```
#!/bin/sh

cat changes.tab | while read line; do
    TARGETDIR="`echo "$line" | awk -F"\t" '{ print $1 }'`"
    COL2="`echo "$line" | awk -F"\t" '{ print $2 }'`"
    COL3="`echo "$line" | awk -F"\t" '{ print $3 }'`"

    if [ -d "$TARGETDIR" ]; then
        cat "$TARGETDIR/index.html" |
        sed "s/Replace with second column/$COL2/g" |
        sed "s/Replace with third column/$COL3/g" > temp
        mv temp "$TARGETDIR/index.html"
    fi
done
```

Test and tweak to your specific needs.  Also, note, this replaces the target files, **so make a safety copy first.**

Comment: thanks!  exactly what I needed.  You're right it was a tsv, I have updated my original post.  I realized that I needed to create index.html in each directory (it doesn't exist yet) so I added `cp index.html "$TARGETDIR"` as the first line of the if loop